# Using `decltype` in IOKit code

Tags: c++, macos, kernel-extension, xnu

When compiling IOKit based kernel extension, the c++ compiler cannot recognize the keyword `decltype`.

```
int f = 123; 
int (*f_ptr)() = 0; 

f_ptr =  (decltype(f_ptr)) f;
```

Compiler fail on the code above for reason : `Use of undeclared identifier 'decltype'`. The `auto` keyword on the other hand, works as expected.

However, if i compile the exact same code in C++ user-mode application, it works fine.

Any idea why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) require C++11 support. Look at your projects **Build Settings** and make sure the **C++ Language Dialect** is at least **GNU++11/C++11** or later (search for the -std= option)

`auto` on the other hand is an [old storage duration specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) keyword re-used in C++11[[6](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)].